# JSOUP Unsupported charset exception

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to read this the following page:

```
http://valencia.loquo.com/cs/vivienda/piso-en-alquiler/312
```

Using the following code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://valencia.loquo.com/cs/vivienda/piso-en-alquiler/312").get();
```

and I get this error:

```
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: ISO-LATIN-1
```

I inspected the HTML response header:

```
Status Code: 200
Date: Sun, 23 Oct 2011 20:10:02 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Pad: avoid browser bug
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 13890
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Debian)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-latin-1
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
```

As you can see the HTML response says **charset=iso-latin-1** probably that is why I get the  error. Anyway I can see the HTML body reponse. There is any way to avoid this error and getting the document (with the standard charset)?

Thanks in advance for your help

Danilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always download the document without JSoup, convert the encoding programmatically (here's a [link to the cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)) and pass the converted String to JSoup.

Comment: Link to the tutorial is broken.

Answer (score 1):

See [ISO_8859_1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#ISO_8859_1)..

> ISO Latin Alphabet No. 1, a.k.a. **ISO-LATIN-1**